# GLM Tweedie dispersion parameter

Tags: generalized-linear-model, dispersion, tweedie-distribution

I am running a tweedie regression and I need to get the dispersion parameter(`phi`).
Here a simple R code:

```r
library(GLMsData)
library(tweedie)
library(statmod)

set.seed(999)
data(quilpie)

out <- tweedie.profile(Rain ~ Phase, do.plot=TRUE, data=quilpie, 
                       link.power = 0)
model <- glm(Rain ~ Phase, data=quilpie, 
             family=tweedie(var.power=out$xi.max, link.power=0))

out$phi.max
summary(model)$dispersion
```

First I am finding the optimal `var.power` coefficient and then fitting the model.
What I don't understand is why the `phi.max` estimate and the `dispersion` estimate are not the same?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the benefit of other readers, Tweedie glms assume that the variance of the responses has the form
$$
{\rm var}(y_i) = \phi \mu_i^\xi
$$
where $\phi$ is the *dispersion* and $\xi$ is the *variance power*.

`tweedie.profile` returns maximum likelihood estimators for $\phi$ and $\xi$.

The dispersion estimator returned by `glm` is different because

1. it is a Pearson estimator based on squared residuals rather than a maximum likelihood estimator and
2. it is adjusted for the fact that the linear model regression parameters have to be estimated, which the maximum likelihood estimator is not.

The dispersion estimator returned by `glm` is more conservative and will generally be slightly larger than that from `tweedie.profile`, especially when the sample size is small or you have a large number of covariates in the linear model.
You can force `glm` to use the maximum likelihood estimate if you want by

```
summary(model, dispersion=out$phi.max)
anova(model, dispersion=out$phi.max)
```

but we recommend that you use the more conservative Pearson estimator from `glm`.

The different dispersion estimators are explained in detail in my book with Peter Dunn:

Dunn, PK, and Smyth, GK (2018). *Generalized linear models with examples in R*. Springer, New York, NY.