# How can Null model likelihood be higher than Fitted model likelihood

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, modeling, model-selection, tweedie-distribution

As far as I know, when fitting a GLM, the fitted model should always have a higher likelihood compared to the null model (with only an intercept) for the same training set. When I run a small simulation, I encounter cases where the opposite happens. What can be the explanation?

Tt comes down to the use of the dispersions parameter, Pearson vs MLE. With MLE of the dispersion parameter the issue is gone.

```
library(statmod)


is_null_higher  <- FALSE 
count <- 0

while (!is_null_higher) {
  count <- count + 1
  x <- rnorm(1000)
  y <- rtweedie(1000, mu=3, phi=2, power=1.5)
  
  df <- data.frame('y' = y, 
                   'x' = x)
  
  model_full <- glm(y ~ x, data=df, family=tweedie(var.power=1.5, link.power=0))
  model_null <- glm(y ~ 1, data=df, family=tweedie(var.power=1.5, link.power=0))
  
  s_null <- summary(model_null)
  s_full <- summary(model_full)
  
  full_lik <- logLiktweedie(model_full, s_full$dispersion)
  null_lik <- logLiktweedie(model_null, s_null$dispersion)
  
  is_null_higher <- full_lik < null_lik
  print(count)
}   

glue::glue('Likelihood Full - {full_lik}, Likelihood Null - {null_lik}')
```

The results are:

```
> glue::glue('Likelihood Full - {full_lik}, Likelihood Null - {null_lik}')
Likelihood Full - -2335.92720478971, Likelihood Null - -2335.92037260135
```

Comment: Where can I find the definition of "logLiktweedie"? (edit: seems to be in the "tweedie" package).

Comment: $1)$ Is the model fit by maximizing likelihood? $2)$ Is there an intercept in the larger model? that `glm` function usually uses an intercept unless you specify to exclude one, but you are combining its functionality with material from another package. $3)$ Could there be a numerical issue where your model has not reached the true optimum?

Comment: I would investigate the details of the fitting procedure because numerical instability could possibly explain this discrepancy.

Comment: I think one reason this happens is because you set the dispersion parameter explicitly in the `logLiktweedie()` call. Aside: There are a few typos in your code though they are easy  to fix. With the [reprex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/index.html) package it's easy to check the code one posts would run without errors.

Comment: In your code, `s_null$dispersion` and `s_full$dispersion` are not max likelihood estimates but Pearson estimators. Hence `full_lik` and `null_lik` are not fully maximized log-likelihoods and the first is not necessarily larger than the second.

Comment: It is worth recalling my answer to you a year ago, where I mentioned that the `summary()` function returns the Pearson estimator of the dispersion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595173/tweedie-dispersion-parameter-estimation-methods. See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440227/glm-tweedie-dispersion-parameter for a discussion of the different dispersion estimators.

Comment: Thanks. There was a bug in my code, when fitting with the MLE of the dispersion parameter, the logliklihood does increase from the null model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon Smyth written in the comments, the issue is the use of the Pearson dispersion estimate vs the MLE of the dispersion.
When using the MLE of the dispersion the results are as expected with higher likelihood to the full model compared to the null model.

```
out_null <- tweedie.profile(y ~ 1, data=df, link.power = 0, p.vec=c(1.5))
out_full <- tweedie.profile(y ~ x, data=df, link.power = 0, p.vec=c(1.5))

full_lik_mle <- logLiktweedie(model_full, out_full$phi.max)
null_lik_mle <- logLiktweedie(model_null, out_null$phi.max)

glue::glue('Likelihood Full - {full_lik_mle}, Likelihood Null - {null_lik_mle}')

> glue::glue('Likelihood Full - {full_lik}, Likelihood Null - {null_lik}')
Likelihood Full - -2335.92720478971, Likelihood Null - -2335.92037260135
> glue::glue('Likelihood Full - {full_lik_mle}, Likelihood Null - {null_lik_mle}')
Likelihood Full - -2335.48808707918, Likelihood Null - -2335.49818069584
```